# Conditional Joint Distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I am given random variables x and y where $f(x,y) = 1$ for $0 <= x, y <= 1$ and 0 elsewhere.  I am asked to find $E[X | Y > X]$.

Here's what I have.  I know I made a mistake somewhere or am misunderstanding something so any help would be appreciated.

I get $f_{x|y}(x, y > \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{f_{xy}(x, y > x)}{f_{y}(y > x)}$.

I get $f_{xy}(x, y > x) = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{x}^{1} 1 {\,dy} {\,dx} = \int_{0}^{1} (1-x) {\,dx}  = 1/2$

I also get ${f_{y}(y > x)} = \int_{x}^{1} 1 {\,dy} = 1-x$

However, that means $f_{x|y}(x, y > \frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2(1-x)}$.

This can't be right since when I plug this into $E[X | Y > X] = \int_{0}^{1} x * \frac{1}{2(1-x)} {\,dx}$, this is an undefined value...so clearly I messed up.  What step am I doing wrong?  Or am I not even approaching the problem in the right way?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the conditional mean of $E(X\mid X&lt;Y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685845/how-to-calculate-the-conditional-mean-of-ex-mid-xy)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where $\frac{1}{2}$ is coming from. You can use the formula

$$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mid X < Y\right) = \frac{\mathbb{E}\left(X1_{\left\{X<Y\right\}}\right)}{P\left(X<Y\right)}.$$

Both the numerator and denominator can be computed using

\begin{eqnarray*}
P\left(X<Y\right) &=& \int^1_0 \int^y_0 1 \,dx\, dy,\\
\mathbb{E}\left(X1_{\left\{X<Y\right\}}\right) &=& \int^1_0 \int^y_0 x \,dx\, dy.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It seems like I am not even using the right formula than in my case.  My question is for your second integral, what does that mean?  Like inside the integral is it just x*f_x(x) which is then x?  Like if f_x(x) = 2 instead, would it be 2x inside that integral?  Or is it f(x,y) * x inside the integral? Is that just saying the general expected value of X where X < Y?  Also I noticed your integral is dx dy rather than dy dx.  Does that make a difference?  Thanks!

Comment: The integral is the unconditional expectation of $f\left(X,Y\right)$, where the function $f$ is given by $f\left(x,y\right) = x1_{\left\{x<y\right\}}$, so you are integrating this function with respect to the joint density. Also $x$ should be on the inside because its value depends on $y$. You first pick a value for $y$ in the outer integral and then integrate over all $x < y$.

Comment: Ok thank you.  I understand.  Sorry, one more question just to make sure I understand.  I see you are taking the integral dx dy.  Can I do dy dx or is there a preferred order I should do it? I guess if I do it dy dx, I have to take it first from y = x to y =1? Nvm, you answered it in your edit!  Thanks!

Comment: You can do it in any order, but either way you have to integrate over the same set, so you need to change the limits of integration accordingly.