# Doubt regarding Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, conditional-probability

Let $X,Y$ be IID random variable that are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Does the following equation hold?
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{E}[X\vert X\geq y]f_Y(y)\,\text{d}y$$
This would then imply that
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_0^1 \text{E}[X\vert X\geq y]\,\text{d}y$$
where
$$f_{X\vert X\geq y}(x) = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{1-y}&y\leq x\leq 1\\0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
such that
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq y] = \int_y^1 x\,\frac{1}{1-y}\,\text{d}x = \frac{1+y}{2}$$
Finally, we obtain
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_0^1 \frac{1+y}{2}\,\text{d}y = \frac{3}{4}$$
which is not correct. Hence, there must be an error somewhere. I appreciate your help!

---

For completeness, the (presumably) correct solution is given below.
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X\vert X\geq Y}(x)\,\text{d}x$$
Using Bayes' rule, we obtain
\begin{align}
f_{X\vert X\geq Y}(x) &= \frac{\text{Pr}[X\geq Y\vert X = x] f_X(x)}{\text{Pr}[X\geq Y]}\\
&= \frac{\text{Pr}[Y\leq x] f_X(x)}{1/2}\\
&= \begin{cases}
2x& x\in[0,1]\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
such that
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot 2x\,\text{d}x = \frac{2}{3}$$

---

### Answer

All credit goes to @Thomas who found the mistake in my initial approach. Thank you @Thomas and thanks to those who added helpful answers or comments.

The main issue lies in my very first equation, namely
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{E}[X\vert X\geq y]f_Y(y)\,\text{d}y$$
As @Thomas suggested, the density $f_Y(y)$ should also be conditioned on $X\geq Y$, that is, $f_{Y\vert X\geq Y}(y)$. The corrected equation is given as
$$\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{E}[X\vert X\geq y]f_{Y\vert X\geq Y}(y)\,\text{d}y$$
with
\begin{align}
f_{Y\vert X\geq Y}(y) &= \frac{P(X\geq Y\vert Y = y)f_Y(y)}{P(X\geq Y)}\\
&= \frac{P(X\geq y)f_Y(y)}{P(X\geq Y)}\\
&= \begin{cases}
\frac{1-y}{1/2} &0\leq y \leq 1\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}
2(1-y) &0\leq y \leq 1\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
This results in the following solution.
\begin{align}
\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{E}[X\vert X\geq y]f_{Y\vert X\geq Y}(y)\,\text{d}y\\
&= \int_0^1 \text{E}[X\vert X\geq y]\,2(1-y)\,\text{d}y\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{1+y}{2}\,2(1-y)\,\text{d}y\\
&= \int_0^1 (1-y^2)\,\text{d}y\\
&= \left[y - \frac{1}{3}\,y^3\right]_0^1\\
&= \frac{2}{3}
\end{align}
where $\text{E}[X\vert X\geq y] = \frac{1+y}{2}$ follows from the computations above (initial approach).

Comment: I don't know why the first equation holds. The definition of $E(X) = \int x f_x(x) \ dx$ so why (for example) are you writing $E(X|Z) = \int E(x|z) f_Z(z) \ dz$?

Comment: @Gregory Note that I refer to random variables when I use upper case letters. Then, we have $\text{E}[X] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{E}[X\vert Y = y]f_Y(y)\,\text{d}y$. In my very first equation, I tried to apply this as follows: $\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y, Y = y]f_Y(y)\,\text{d}y$, which should be equivalent to $\text{E}[X\vert X\geq Y] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{E}[X\vert X\geq y]f_Y(y)\,\text{d}y$.

Comment: You are conditioning on an event, not a random variable. Thus, you should get $$\dfrac{\int\limits_{1 \geq x \geq y \geq 0} x d(x,y)}{\int\limits_{1 \geq x \geq y \geq 0} d(x,y)} = \frac{1/3}{1/2} = \dfrac{2}{3}.$$

Comment: And let me state it again, since you are conditioning on an event, you get a trivial conditioning on the density (just divide by the probability of the conditioning event). That is, the density of $(X, Y)$ given $X \geq Y$ is $\dfrac{1}{1/2} = 2$ on the subset of $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$ such that $x \geq y.$ Note that on this triangle, $X$ and $Y$ are no longer independent and you have to use the joint density $E(X) = \int_{1 \geq x \geq y \geq 0} 2x d(x,y) = \int_0^1 dx\ 2x \int_0^x dy = \int_0^1 2x^2 dx = \dfrac{2}{3},$ and everything is good.

Comment: Last comment: never mix conditioning on events with conditioning on random variables. The two things are really quite different things! In other words, things like $E(X \mid A) = \int_y E(X \mid A, Y = y) f_Y(y) dy$ don't really make sense!

Comment: @WilliamM."never mix conditioning"... So what is wrong with $E[X|A]=\frac{1}{P(A)}E[X\mathbf{1}_A]=\frac{1}{P(A)}E[E[X\mathbf{1}_A|Y]]$?

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks for your helpful comments. Your approach of solving the problem makes sense to me. However, what remains unclear is why we should "never mix conditioning on events with conditioning on random variables." The condition on the random variable $Y = y$ is (or can be) an event as well, right? And also, what is the reason why we should avoid to "mix conditioning on events with conditioning on random variables"?

Comment: When an event has positive probability, conditioning on it simply means to redefine the probability space to be the event and adjust the size of the new measure to be 1 on the event. Conditioning on a random variable is a construction that invokes Lebesgue-Nykodim theorem on derivatives of one measure relatice to another measure and so the conditioning variable is defined only up to null events. The amazing fact is that when a random variable is discrete or when the densities are (sufficiently) regular you can think of the condition as $y-h<Y\leq y+h$ and let $h \to 0,$ this is consistent.

Comment: @WilliamM. Great, thanks for your help.

Comment: There are more straightforward ways to find the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2685845/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3697245/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all we can recall the tower property. If we have a partition of the probability space $A_i$, with $P(A_i)>0$, than:

$E[X]=\sum_i E[X|A_i]P(A_i)$

If we have an event $B$ this reads:

$E[X|B]=\sum_i E[X|A_i,B]P(A_i|B)$ [1]

Now consider $B=\{X>Y\}$ and $A_y=\{Y=y\}$. We would be tempted to guess from [1]:

$E[X|X>Y]=\int dy E[X|Y=y,X>Y]P(Y=y|X>Y)$ [2]

This is similar to your formula in spirit, but note that we have a conditional density on P.

But the problem here is that also this formula is undefined because we are conditioning on null events, something that is undefined. Nevertheless, if we consider a $y_1=0,...,y_n=1$ equidistant with distant $\Delta$ and consider the events $A_i=\{Y \in [y_i,y_{i+i}]\}$ we have a well defined expression, similar to 2, but with summations instead of integrals. We can than let $\Delta \rightarrow 0$.

If you do that, you see that you need to substitute :

- $E[X|Y=y,X>Y] \rightarrow \frac{1+y}{2}$ (your result) ;
- $P(Y=y|X>Y)\rightarrow 2(1-y)$ (here is where your calculation is wrong I think);

, which leads to the correct result (2/3). Something that one could have also 'guessed'.

Of course there is a more direct way to solve the exercise but here I wanted to show how to change your first approach so that you get the correct result.

Comment: If you have an event $B$ and define a new measure by $Q(A)=P(A\mid B)$ then $Q$ is a legitimate probability measure and all results apply to $Q$ which entail that you can do the law of total probability (what you called "tower property", which by the way, I know it to mean that two iterated conditional expectations is the same as conditioning on the smallest sigma field). I guess in this sense you can mix "conditioning on events and random variables" but the notation gets obfuscated.